# Duel citizen US/Japan Can I use my Japanese passport to enter China?

Tags: passports, china, dual-nationality, japanese-citizens

Duel citizen US/Japan.

Can I use my Japanese passport to enter China 16 days?

My flight is a round trip from US. I’m under 15.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, the Japanese passport lets you visit China visa free.  Just follow the guidance here: [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel?noredirect=1&lq=1)